# Deamon Process Crash(dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries)

Tags: objective-c

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:

Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSFrameView.closeButton

Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/IDriveforMac/*/IDSyncDaemon.app/Contents/MacOS/IDSyncDaemon

Expected in:

/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Library/Application Support/IDriveforMac/*/IDSyncDaemon.app/Contents/MacOS/IDSyncDaemon

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you, at best, have an outdated version if iDrive or some other ProSoftNet product installed.   At worst, they have a daemon that is putting up UI directly and the code is outdated.

Either way, their daemon is trying to use a symbol from Cocoa’s AppKit framework that does not exit.

What version of macOS are you on?